# Is there a way in plain javascript to select element in options by value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

As you can see from the title, I am wondering if there is a way in plain javascript to select an element from option fields by some value. I know I can do it with jQuery like this - `option[value="'+  myObject.value+'"]` but I want to know if I can do the same with javascript without using some loop to find the index and then select it by its value.

P.S. I guess jQuery is doing exactly this^ but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) with css [attribute equals selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```
var ele = document.querySelector('option[value="' + myObject.value+ '"]');
```

Comment: I tried to do it with querySelector but I guess I missed something. Thanks for the fast reply.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as easily in plain JavaScript by using [**`document.querySelectorAll`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
document.querySelectorAll("option[value='" + myObject.value + "']");
```